# Create objects and their object properties inside a for each

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I want to create properties from array values from an object that already has a name. I mean I don't want to push anonymous objects like push({date: //whatever}) .

This is my code:

```js
var obj= {}
var arrayObjects= []

var dates= ["Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017"]


for(var i=0; i< dates.length; i++){

  arrayObjects.push( obj["date"]= dates[i])
}
```

But I'm only getting in the arrayObjects dates:

```js
["Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017"]
```

And what I want is an array of the obj with each date from the array, like:

```js
[Object {date: "Mar 01, 2017"}, Object {date: "Mar 02, 2017"}] //...
```

Comment: Why don't you want to push anonymous objects ? What would be the difference with your wanted output ?

Comment: It's funny that there are 4 answers so far and **none** of them uses a `forEach`.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I added one

Comment: @Weedoze  Because I will need to use the same object later on to repeat the process in an asynchronous operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Array#reduce`.

```js
var dates = ["Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017"],
    result = dates.reduce(function(s,a){
      var obj = {};
      obj.date = a;
      s.push(obj);
      return s;
    }, []);
      
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: dv not from me, but it's a kind of unusual approach to replace [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) by [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), where map is the method to use. it is exactly made for this, to return for every element of the array an element for a new array. beside that, you loose the ability to use `thisArg` and need to return the array for every iteration. conclusion: it works with reduce, but map is better.

Comment: @NinaScholz There's a text appearing over the downvote button, *this answer is not useful*. Maybe it's better to use `map` instead, hovewer I highly doubt that this answer is not useful at all.

Answer (score 2):

You could generate objects and push them to the result set.

```js
var arrayObjects = [],
    dates= ["Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017"],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
    arrayObjects.push({ date: dates[i] });
}

console.log(arrayObjects);
```

Or use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var dates = ["Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017"],
    arrayObjects = dates.map(function (a) {
        return { date: a };
    });

console.log(arrayObjects);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget the semicolon `;` . also, you don't have to use the `obj`.

Simply use `{date:dates[i]}`

```js
var arrayObjects= [];

var dates= ["Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017"];


for(var i=0; i< dates.length; i++){

  arrayObjects.push( {date: dates[i]});
}
console.log(arrayObjects);
```

From the Title

Using `forEach`

```js
var arrayObjects= [];

var dates= ["Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017"];

dates.forEach(x=> arrayObjects.push({date:x}));
console.log(arrayObjects);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` to return array of objects.

```js
var dates= ["Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017"]

var arrayObjects = dates.map(function(date) {
  return {date: date}
})
console.log(arrayObjects)
```

Or using ES6 arrow functions you can do the same like this.

```
var arrayObjects = dates.map(e => ({date: e}))
```

Answer (score 0):

your code contains:

```
arrayObjects.push( obj["date"]= dates[i])
```

this will set the property obj.date to each element of dates and pushing the assigned string value to arrayObjects.

use

```
arrayObjects.push( { date: dates[i]} )
```

to create an object vor each string value.
this will make your initial statement

```
var obj= {}
```

obsolete as long as you don't use it anywhere else...

Comment: The thing is that I want to use it somewhere else in an asynchronous operation...

Answer (score 0):

You can use ES6 [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) method to iterate over `dates` array pushing elements to `arrayObjects`:

```js
const dates = ["Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 02, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017", "Mar 01, 2017"];
const arrayObjects = [];

for (d of dates) {
  arrayObjects.push({date: d});
}

console.log(arrayObjects);
```